# Can't get Regex to stop returning empty strings and in a list format

Tags: python, regex

### My Goal

I'm trying to create a program that separates out certain parts of a string into a list so that they can be used to create a table with three elements:

1. Class code
2. Class title
3. Class section number

I tried using regex, thinking it would be faster (silly me), but I've been wrestling with it for about two hours now, and I just can't seem to figure out what's going on with it. It either keeps giving me back empty strings, or it gives me what I want, but in a new list.

```
"""

A program that separates the raw data out of a list,
and puts it in all into neatly organized tables
"""

""" Function that will split up a string
and place each part into an appropiate list """

import re

def dataSorter(rawData):
    
    # list where sorted items will go
    sortedList = []

    #classCode = re.split('[^a-zA-Z]', rawData)

    # Separates the class code and puts it in the sortedList
    classCode = rawData[:5]
    sortedList.append(classCode)

    classTitle = re.findall('\D*', rawData[5:])
    sortedList.append(classTitle)

    #classNumber = re.findall('[0-9]*', rawData[5:])
    #sortedList.append(classNumber)


    print(sortedList)




def main():
    courses = ['CS152Introduction to Python Programming21',
               'CS369Operating Systems Administration8',
               'CS352Data Structures19',
               'CS208Discrete Mathematics124',
               'CS319Computer Architecture14',
               'MA221Calculus and Analytical Geometry for Majors I12',
               'MA311Linear Algebra7',
               'MA150Precalculus Mathematics27',
               'CS335Introduction to Cybersecurity20',
               'IS361Data Management Systems22',
               'MG315Advanced Business Statistics6' ]
               
            
    testTable = "CS155IntrotoButt21"

    dataSorter(testTable)

main()
```

What I keep expecting in the sortedList variable, is:
`['CS155', 'IntrotoButt']`

Instead, I keep getting:
`['CS155', ['IntrotoButt', '', '', '']]`

### What I've tried

The closest I've gotten to the results I want was when I made the code like this:

```
A program that separates the raw data out of a list,
and puts it in all into neatly organized tables
"""

""" Function that will split up a string
and place each part into an appropiate list """

import re

def dataSorter(rawData):
    
    # list where sorted items will go
    sortedList = []

    #classCode = re.split('[^a-zA-Z]', rawData)

    # Separates the class code and puts it in the sortedList
    classCode = rawData[:5]
    sortedList.append(classCode)

    classTitle = re.findall('[^0-9][a-zA-Z]*', rawData[5:])
    sortedList.append(classTitle)

    classNumber = re.findall('[0-9]', rawData[5:])


    print(sortedList)




def main():
    courses = ['CS152Introduction to Python Programming21',
               'CS369Operating Systems Administration8',
               'CS352Data Structures19',
               'CS208Discrete Mathematics124',
               'CS319Computer Architecture14',
               'MA221Calculus and Analytical Geometry for Majors I12',
               'MA311Linear Algebra7',
               'MA150Precalculus Mathematics27',
               'CS335Introduction to Cybersecurity20',
               'IS361Data Management Systems22',
               'MG315Advanced Business Statistics6' ]
               
            
    testTable = "CS155IntrotoButt21"

    dataSorter(testTable)

main()
```

But even then, I just end up with this:
`['CS155', ['IntrotoButt']]`

And I have no idea why the `classTitle` variable puts itself into a new list that's INSIDE `sortedList`.

I know it's something I'm misunderstanding with regex or how lists work. What am I not understanding?

Comment: Use `+` instead of `*` where you need to match at least one char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `dataSorter` function with the following:

```
def dataSorter(rawData):
    match = re.match('^(.{5})(.*?)([0-9]*)$', rawData)
    print(match.groups())
```

Actually, the result is a tuple instead of a list. If you really need a list, use `list(match.groups()))`.

Explanation: The regular expression contains three parenthesized groups. The first one simply matches the first five characters, no matter what they are. The last group matches any amount of digits at the end. The middle group matches everything else between them.

**Edit:** In your code, `IntrotoButt` ends up in a sub-list because re.findall() returns a list, not a string.

Comment: Every time I try to use `re.match` I get ` <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f20843922b0>`. Why is that? Also is regex the simplest way to solve this problem?

Comment: @KeterRobinson The official [documentation on Python regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) is quite good. Also there are lots of regex tutorials on the web (just ask Google).

Comment: @KeterRobinson Well, `re.match()` returns a match object. A match object has several methods that can be used, for example the `groups()` method returns a tuple of the strings that have been matched by the sub-groups of the regex (if any). Again, please refer to the [Python documentation on match objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) for details.

Comment: Yeah, I sometimes forget most of coding is just, sitting down and learning how the thing WORKS before implementing it. Thank you for your patience.